# Could not open input file: composer.phar while new laravel project is created

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php, laravel-5

I have installed composer globally using the steps mentioned in https://getcomposer.org/

But after installing Laravel framework, when I create a new laravel project, the following error is thrown.

Could not open input file: composer.phar

But the project gets initialized in the back. What is the issue ?

Comment: try this command `composer` in terminal, see what results you get ?

Comment: @Qazi It runs composer shows everything that is related to it. I have installed composer globally.

Comment: ok, then how you are trying to open `composer.phar` file? can you tell the command ?

Comment: @Qazi I m typing this command in the terminal : laravel new myproject. And after that I'm getting the error- Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: why dont you try this way https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installing-laravel  this mentioned on laravel site, and well working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was while installing the composer was installed both globally as well as locally and due to this the referencing issue rose. After the local installation was removed, the project was successfully installed with all the dependencies.

Comment: How to remove the 'local' installation?

Comment: remove composer.phar file and .composer folder

Answer (score 0):

There is a param in nginx may be effect.

```
PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=$document_root/:/tmp/:/proc/";
```

You can check up this param in fastcgi.conf

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my english is not very good, I've solved it changing the function "findComposer()" inside of ".composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php"

```
protected function findComposer()
{
    if (file_exists(getcwd().'/composer')) {
        return '"'.PHP_BINARY.'" composer';
    }

    return 'composer';
}
```